# rewriting azure webapp from non-www to www

Tags: azure, iis

I want to rewrite any Url to beging with https://www.example.com. It works using the following configuration, but when I made a request to 
https://example.com it fails.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS and www" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: what is exactly the "fail" output?

Comment: @BrunoFaria it doesn't redirect me to https://www.example.com.

Comment: what happens when you try to access http://example.com? without https and www

Comment: @BrunoFaria I got https :// www .example.com

Answer (score 0):

Use two rules, one for HTTPS and for for your canonical redirect:

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="false" xdt:Transform="Insert">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<rule name="Canonical Host Name" stopProcessing="false" xdt:Transform="Insert">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^(www\.example\.com)$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: If I want a domain agnostic solution, can I remove example.com from "Canonical Host Name" pattern, and change url to url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"

Comment: how can I debug those rules?